# Does irreducibility corresponds to maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

I have recently studied prime ideals,maximal ideals and divisibility in an integral domain.Suppose $a$ is an irreducible element in an integral domain $D$,can we claim that $(a)$ is a maximal element of $D$.But then $(a)$ is a prime ideal,then $a$ is prime as $a\neq 0$.But the it proves that every irreducible is prime but this is not true.In particular consider $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and the element $2$,it is irreducible but not prime,So,$(2)$ is not a prime ideal ,so it cannot be maximal as well.But $2$ is irreducible.

Actually I was trying to draw an analogy with the theorem:

In an integral domain $D$,an element $a$ is prime iff $(a)$ is prime and $a\neq 0$.

I was trying to replace **prime** by **irreducible** and **prime ideal** by **maximal ideal** but you see in the above statement where this does not hold.

So my question is,what is a necessary sufficient condition that $(a)$ is maximal iff $a$ is irreducible.It is clear to me that $(a)$ is maximal and $a\neq 0$ would imply $a$ is irreducible.But when does the converse hold?

Comment: You may add integral domain and Noetherian (no infinite strictly increasing chain of ideals) to make it easier, in that case every irreducible is a maximal ideal iff $R$ is a PID (you can factorize any principal ideal in a **finite** product of principal maximal ideals, if $I$ is not principal then there is a non-principal maximal ideal $m$ containing $I$, let $a\in m$ then $(a) = \prod_j( m_j)^{e_j}$ and since $m,\prod_j( m_j)^{e_j}$ are comaximal we get a contradiction)

Comment: Without the Noetherian assumption there is $k[y]_{(y)}+xk(y)[x]_{(x)}$ whose only maximal ideal is $(y)$ and whose other prime ideals are $0$ and $xk(y)[x]_{(x)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very definition of "irreducible" can be rephrased as "maximal among principal ideals."

So for a given irreducible element $(a)$, we have that $(a)$ is a maximal ideal if and only if every maximal ideal containing $a$ is principal.